# Видео-ролик со старта на весь экран

Tags: html, видео

Здравствуйте. Нужно на сайте со старта запустить видео-ролик на весь экран (и с кнопкой пропустить, но не в этом проблема). Это должно работать под мобильные браузеры, старые браузеры (без HTML5), от IE-7 и без флеша.
HTML5 - чтоб играло на Android, iOS и пр. мобильных. Под современные браузеры - это тоже лучшее решение.
Остается только придумать костыли под IE7 и старые браузеры.
Есть идеи?

Comment: В общем-то, флеш - это и есть тот самый костыль, если так можно назвать, про который вы говорите. Все современные плееры, которые работают во всех браузерах, используют или HTML5, или Flash, в зависимости от того, в каком браузере ролик проигрывается.

Comment: @Deonis, никогда с плеерами дел не имел. Думал может чего не знаю.  
П.С. Silverlight по умолчанию в IE не идет случайно?

Comment: @Андрей Бакша, не идёт... а уж там, где стоит 7-й ослик тем более не идёт)

Comment: @lampa, спасибо! Это хоть какое-то решение, хоть я и не считаю, что лучшее, чем флеш. Но заказчику кто-то "нашептал", что надо без флеша.  
Преобразуйте комментарий в ответ. Помечу как правильный.

Comment: @Андрей Бакша ну чем не устраивает?) Там даже есть управление через js. И в windows mobile вроде как работает.

Comment: @lampa, не знаю) Костыльно как-то именно в данной задаче) Там надо, чтоб сразу проигрывалось, а IE еще спрашивает разрешение о доступе к плееру. Если WMP не установлен, то ничего(( Но все равно это лучшее решение. Спасибо огромное еще раз!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть такая штука, как встраиваемый windows media:

```
<object width="280" height="350" type="application/x-mplayer2">
   <param name="fileName" value="http://www.danielbryden.net/lights.wmv">
   <param name="autostart" value="1">
   <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="1">
</object>
```